# 125VAC relay with 230VAC

Tags: relay

I bought a relay and until home hasn't noticed that its limited to `1A 125VAC`. Then I found this [datasheet](http://www.tme.eu/en/Document/c23d5af46047cd50f4ab84101c968917/rs.pdf) which says that it can be used for 250V. I live in Europe so I thought that maybe that relay was produced for American market and despite that indication on its casing, it can be used with 250V. Is this possible?

Comment: The datasheet in your link seems to be for a safety pull switch, not a relay.  Please verify what you have.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I got this one: http://www.tme.eu/en/details/rs-5/miniature-electromagnetic-relays/rayex-electronic/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see no mention of 250 volts on the (corrected) datasheet.  The only contact ratings given are 125VAC @ 1 Amp, so it would be unsafe to use it to switch 240 volts.